# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int' ---don't understand the error

Tags: python, int, tuples, typeerror

I'm trying to run a code only I don't understand this error:

```
  if AC_energy / pow == 1:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

The piece of code :

```py
  Power = (5, 10, 15, 20)

  for pow in Power:

   for Hours in range(1, 6):

       AC_energy = Power * Hours

       print(AC_energy)

       if AC_energy / pow == 1:

          Rack_energy = 230

       else:
          Rack_energy = 288

       Nbr_rack = ((AC_energy *(1 + 0.2)) *1000) / Rack_energy

       Energy = ((Rack_energy * Nbr_rack)/ 1000)* 0.95
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `Power` is a tuple `(5, 10, 15, 20)`. This tuple multiplied by `Hours` will duplicate it `Hours` times, so for `Hours == 2` it would make `AC_energy = (5, 10, 15, 20) * 2` i.e. `AC_energy = (5, 10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20)`. But then you take that tuple and attempt to divide it by `pow` (for example `5`), and you cannot divide a tuple by a scalar number, hence the error (`(5, 10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20) / 5` is not a valid operation).

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
What I want to do is multiply each power number by hours i.e.( 5* 1 then 5*2 then 5*15 ...) 
When I change Power to a list ( Power = [5, 10, 15, 20] ) I get a syntax error.

Comment: if AC_energy / Power = 1:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3):

You are multiplying a tuple with an integer at the beginning. The result is a tuple and you get an error when dividing it with an integer.

```
>>> (5, 10, 15, 20) * 6
(5, 10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20, 5, 10, 15, 20)
```

What you might want to do is to change the line

```
AC_energy = Power * Hours
```

with

```
AC_energy = pow * Hours
```

Comment: I did what you said : Power = [5, 10, 15, 20]
for pow in Power:
   for Hours in range(1, 6):
       AC_energy = Pow * Hours
       print(AC_energy)
       if AC_energy / Pow == 1:
          Rack_energy = 230